# Varities of hops to grow in upstate New York

Tags: hops

Looking for hops that do well in upstate NY (zone 6a).

I am currently growing Willamette and Cascade.  The Willamette did very well this year.  Cascades didn't produce enough to make anything with.

When I put the hops in 3-4 years ago, I also planted Nugget, Kent Golding and Chinook and none of them really got established enough over a couple of grouwing seasons.  Those were planned on a less-sunny side of the yard with say 5-8 hours of sunlight per day. There is also a walnut tree nearby.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in lower NY (zone 6b) and my Columbus and Centennial did very well this year with 7 - 8 hours of sun each day.  My Willamette and Nugget did not do very well, but this was their first year.

Any varieties that are susceptible to downy mildew might not do well, but if you space them out well (5 feet or so between crowns), water or drip irrigate at the soil, and keep the lower portions of the bines clear for proper aeration, you probably won't have a problem. Like I said, my Columbus did well.

There's a lot of info here about the varieties - http://www.freshops.com/hops/usda-named-hop-variety-descriptions